# Saving structs to file

Tags: c, struct, file-io

I am trying to save a list of structs to a file and load them later.

I want to output the data of the first object from the object array, but when I try to load and print an object of the structure through his pointer (variables: `name`, `age`) The program's output is something like this: `Name:  | Age: 0`.

What's expected is: `Name: Tom | Age: 15`.

(For the example input of `person object[3] = {"Tom", 15, "Andrew", 25, "Kate", 55};`).

I try to use `fseek` function for this, how can I use it to print only the first object?

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    typedef struct
    {
        char name[20];
        int age;
    } person;

    void save(int x, char way[100], person (*p_object)[x]);
    void load(char way[100], int x);

    FILE *file;

    int main(void)
    {
        char way[100] = "D:\\Projects\\C\\C06_WorkingWithFiles\\C005_PositioningInTheStream.dat";
        person object[3] = {"Tom", 15, "Andrew", 25, "Kate", 55};
        person (*p_object)[3] = &object;
        save((sizeof(*p_object) / sizeof(*p_object)[0]), way, p_object);
        load(way, 1);
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    void save(int x, char way[100], person (*p_object)[x])
    {
        if (fopen(way, "r") == NULL)
        {
            file = fopen(way, "w");
        }

        char *c = (char *)p_object;
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*p_object); i++)
        {
            putc(*c, file);
            c++;
        }
    }

    void load(char way[100], int x)
    {
        if ((fopen(way, "r")) == NULL)
        {
            perror("\nError");
            exit(0);
        }

        int position = sizeof(person) * x;
        fseek(file, position, SEEK_SET);

        person object, *p_object = &object;
        char symbol, *c = (char *)p_object;
        while ((symbol = getc(file)) != EOF)
        {
            *c = symbol;
            c++;
        }
        printf("\nName: %s | Age: %d\n", p_object -> name, p_object -> age);
    }
```

Comment: Is it saving data to the file? You are checking if file exist, in case yes then you are not instantiating the 'file' pointer. So in case file exists it wont save data. Better to use fopen()/fclose in pair in both save() and load() functions and assign fopen to the  'file' pointer variable in each of these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation that does what you ask:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int age;
} person;

void save(int num, char path[100], person (*p_object)[num]);

person load(char path[100], int index);


int main(void) {
    char path[100] = "output.dat";
    person persons[3] = {"Tom", 15, "Andrew", 25, "Kate", 55};

    save(3, path, &persons);
    person object = load(path, 1);
    printf("\nName: %s | Age: %d\n", object.name, object.age);

    return 0;
}

void save(int num, char path[100], person (*p_object)[num]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "w+");
    fwrite(p_object, sizeof(person), num, file);
    fclose(file);
}

person load(char path[100], int index) {
    person object;
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r");
    fseek(file, (long) sizeof(person) * index, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&object, sizeof(person), 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    return object;
}
```

Note that it's better to use existing functions [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) and [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/) instead of implementing it yourself.

This will make your code simpler and more straight forward.

Also, your implementation for `fread` is not correct, since EOF can appear there, because you're writing a binary data, you need to read the whole size of the struct to load it.

Comment: It would be useful to point out specific problems with the code and what your code does to avoid that.

Comment: Updated the "bug" part, my implementation changed a bit more things just to improve the code, not only fix it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer about 'fwrite' and 'fread' functions. I didn't know this. It's more convenient than my own realization